# Connecting 2 tables for INSERT UPDATE and DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all I am newbie so bear with me.

I have 2 tables `ABC` (with columns `A, B, C`) and `ABCLogs` (`oA, oB, oC, nA, nB, nC`). I want to write a trigger on `ABC` so that whenever I insert, update or delete any values from `ABC`, it should be reflected in `ABCLogs` in the respective columns with new values and old values

Note:

- `nA`: New value of column `A` in table `ABC`
- `oA`: Old value of column `A` in table `ABC`

Let me know any further information is needed.

Thanks

Following is Done:

```
    SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    SET @action = 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
            ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
        END
END
ELSE 
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;
```

IF @action ='I'
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[nABC](nA, nB, nC) SELECT A,B,C FROM INSERTED

Above line only updates new values into nABC, now i want to extract the old value of new values that is inserted into nA( of nABC) from A(of ABC), i am not able to do that, is there a way to extract the last value of from ABC?

Comment: What problems are you facing in writing the query? Share your code please.

Comment: First of all, the table design should be changed. Making columns A, B, C, it will make the work harder. Just make two columns ID and values. Finally insert whatever the values are.

Comment: For heads up, i created 3 table(ABC, oABC, nABC) thought of creating output joining oABC and nABC

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service where you just dump your requirements and expect others to write your code for you. You should show **some of YOUR OWN** effort first! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What works, what doesn't ?